# ngGridEventScroll is hitting two times

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using a grid and trying to load data on scroll event. But it is hitting two times on scroll event.

```
scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function () {
// code to load data
}
```

I also found below piece of code which is emitting the scroll event twice. it's in ng-grid.js file.

```
 $scope.adjustScrollTop = function(scrollTop, force) {
        if (self.prevScrollTop === scrollTop && !force) {
            return;
        }
        if (scrollTop > 0 && self.$viewport[0].scrollHeight - scrollTop <= self.$viewport.outerHeight()) {
            $scope.$emit('ngGridEventScroll');
        }
```

Value of force is being passed true, that's why second time its not returning from function.

if i hack ng-grid and change the value of force to false(as suggested in below link), it works fine. but i don't want to change ng-grid code.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/llT35QGig9Y